# How to check balance of covariates for treatment effects?

Tags: stata, matching

I'm using propensity score matching in Stata 13 like this:

```
. teffects psmatch (outcome_var) (treatment_var covar_1 covar_2 etc.)
```

So I've got statistically significant results, but I need to check the balance of the covariates.

I see that Stata 14 has a command `tebalance summarize` to do this but not in 13. Does anyone know how to check it?

Just to be sure, I tried anyway:

```
. tebalance summarize
unrecognized command:  tebalance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tests that you can do by hand. I think the most common is to regress each covariate on a polynomial of the propensity score of degree K (so PS, PS^2, PS^3,...) plus the same terms interacted with treatment dummy (D, DxPS, DxPS^2, DxPS^3). Then you do a joint test that all the coefficients on treated-PS^k interactions are zero for k=0,..,K.

If balance has been achieved then the coefficients on all the interactions should equal zero, because the treated unit should not have a different regression line than the untreated units.

Another alternative is to use the user-written matching command like `psmatch2`, which does balancing tests with `pstest`.